# Is $a\pi(x) \ge \pi(ax)$ where $a$ is a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This seems to be intuitively true but I am having trouble proving it.  I suspect that it has a very easy proof.

I am dividing up $ax$ into $a$ sequences of $x$ consecutive integers.

I am trying to show that for each sequence $\pi(cx+c) - \pi(cx) \le \pi(x)$ where $1 \le c \le a$.

I am dividing up each sequence into different residue classes relative integers equal or less than $x$

I am finding it very difficult to get a lower bound on counting these residue classes so maybe this approach is not the right way to go.

Is this problem as simple as it appears?  What approaches can be used for the argument?

Comment: Is $a$ an integer?  It isn't true for general $a$ (e.g. $\pi(10)= 4$ and $\pi(19)=8$).

Comment: Yes, I'm only thinking about $a$ as an integer.

Comment: @daniel, are there any counter examples before $x$ gets sufficiently large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this for given $a$ requires explicit bounds on the error of the prime number theorem. If you use, for example, $a = 1000$ and Dusart's very modest bounds as given in the Wiki article for $x\geq55,$ you can show that the bounds on the respective expressions are mutually exclusive well before $x = 100. $

Better results require better bounds (and there is no shortage). In this way you can reduce the problem to disposing of fairly small finite numbers.

Comment: Will try to fix this up soon. These are really modest bounds.

Comment: Thanks very much for your analysis.  This is very helpful.

Comment: On the other hand, it is widely believed to be false that for all $x,y$, $\pi(x+y)\le\pi(x)+\pi(y)$.