# Proving that $\pi(2x) < 2 \pi(x) $

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

In our analytic number theory class we were given the following problem as homework: prove rigorously that for large $x$ the number of primes in $(1,x]$ exceeds that in $(x,2x]$.

In class we proved the prime number theorem, and then proceeded to prove several results such as $\pi(x) = Li(x) +O(x^\theta \ln x)$ and the explicit formula for $\psi_1(x)$.

This is clearly quite intuitive but I'm lost as to what I can use to prove the result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have bounds on $\theta$?

Comment: So... I think we are stuck with proving $Li(2x)<2Li(x)$?

Comment: @abiessu all we know is that $ 1/2 \leq \theta \leq 1 $.

Comment: @mathstudent_113 that's not really a bound on theta then since $\pi(x)\leq x$. Do you mean $1/2\leq \theta <1$?

Comment: It can be shown that $\pi(ax) \le a\pi(x)$: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1664810/48606

Comment: @LarryFreeman Nice, but I don't really feel the answer is as good as it could be.

Comment: @Simple Art, intuitively, I agree.  If you have an improved result, I would be very interested in seeing it.

Comment: @LarryFreeman I'll see if I can

Comment: @Jake The inequality for a given $\theta$ implies to the non-existence of zeros of the Riemann zeta function with real part between $\theta$ and $1$.  In particular, no result of such strength is known for $\theta < 1$ (search for keyword "zero-free region" for the strongest known results), and therefore there is no known proof of $\pi(x) = \text{Li}(x) + O(x^\theta \ln x)$ for any $\theta$ that is non-trivial.

Comment: I answered this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426666/a-particular-cases-of-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture/1427143#1427143

Answer (score 6):

It can be shown that for $x \ge 11$, $\pi(2x) < 2\pi(x)$

- For $x=1$, it is not true since $2\pi(1) = 0$ but $\pi(2)=1$
- For $x \in \{2,4,10\}$, $2\pi(x)=\pi(2x)$

Pierre Dusart [showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) that for $x \ge 60184$

$$\frac{x}{\ln{x}-1} < \pi(x) < \frac{x}{\ln {x}-1.1}$$

- For the proof, see Theorem 6.9 [here](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf).

For $a \ge 2$, $\ln ax - 1.1 = \ln a + \ln x - 1.1 \ge \ln 2 - 1.1 + \ln x > \ln x - 0.41 > \ln x - 1$

So, it follows that for $x \ge 60184, a \ge 2$:

$$\pi(ax) < \frac{ax}{\log{ax}-1.1} < \frac{ax}{\log x - 1} < a\pi(x)$$

By brute force, it can be shown that in all cases where $x < 60184$, $\pi(2x) < 2\pi(x)$.

Here is java code that I used to verify it (adding an image only):

[image]

Comment: This is very nice, but then I would have to know how Dusart got his result. Anyway we only need to show for large $x$ so there's no need to verify it for $x<60184$ I think.

Comment: Here is a link to the Dusart article: http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't my main area of study, I do think we are stuck with proving $Li(2x)<2Li(x)$ (ignoring $O(x^{\theta}\ln(x))$) for large $x$.

The definition of the offset logarithmic integral is

$$Li(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\ln(t)}$$

We want to take this and prove that $Li(2x)<2Li(x)$.

Since $\frac{d}{dx}Li(x)=\frac1{\ln(x)}>0$, we see that the offset logarithmic integral has a positive derivative.  Since $\frac{d}{dx}\frac1{\ln(x)}=\frac{-1}{x(\ln(x))^2}<0$, we know this function is concave.

This implies that for large enough $x$, $Li(2x)<2Li(x)$ since $Li(x)$ is concave.  I'm not quite sure how to do a formal proof or whatever, but I imagine we can go along those lines.

If $Li(2x)<2Li(x)$, I would think

$$\frac{d}{dx}Li(2x)<\frac{d}{dx}2Li(x)$$

$$\frac2{\ln(2x)}<\frac2{\ln(x)}$$

And the last line is much easier to prove.

Comment: Just as a question, is there a more formal way to do this?  I really just took some thoughts about how the graphs should look and tried to put it into math, but I'm not even sure if that's really the right way to go...