# Show $\pi (X) \leq 2 \pi (X/2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi (X)$ be the prime counting function. How can I prove that, for large enough $X$, $\pi (X) \leq 2 \pi (X/2)$?
I have tried applying the Prime Number Theorem, but cannot see a way to get the result from it. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $\pi(2x) &lt; 2 \pi(x) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738347/proving-that-pi2x-2-pix)

Comment: I'm interested in seeing if you can prove this weaker statement by a more elementary method

Answer (score 1):

By using the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), it follows that
 $$\lim_{X\to +\infty} \frac{\pi(X)}{\pi(X/2)}=\lim_{X\to +\infty} \frac{X/\ln(X)}{(X/2)/\ln(X/2)}=2\lim_{X\to +\infty} \frac{\ln(X)-\ln(2)}{\ln(X)}=2$$
which implies that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $M_{\epsilon}>0$ such that for $X>M_{\epsilon}$,
$$\pi (X) < (2+\epsilon) \pi (X/2).$$

For your inequality, you need a more refined analysis. See [Proving that $\pi(2x) < 2 \pi(x) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738347/proving-that-pi2x-2-pix)