# Show that $n^{\pi\left(2n\right)-\pi\left(n\right)}<2^{2n}$ and $2^n\le\left(2n\right)^{\pi(2n)}$ for all $n>2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I may not use the Prime Number Theorem (and even if I could, it would only show the desired claim for sufficiently-large $n$).

I have tried induction on $n^{\pi\left(2n\right)-\pi\left(n\right)}<2^{2n}$. For the induction step we have: $$n^{\pi\left(2n+2\right)-\pi\left(n+1\right)} \le n^{\pi\left(2n+2\right)-\pi\left(n\right)}
 \le n^{\pi\left(2n\right)+1-\pi\left(n\right)}
 <2^{2n}n$$

Which isn't less than $2^{2n+2}$.

Any advice is very welcome.

Comment: you can prove it by PNT for all number with few cases to be checked and not for sufficiently large $n$, but i am assuming you want induction way to prove the above.

Comment: It's surely a legitimate solution if I can pinpoint the cases to be manually checked, but how would I go about doing that? (I'm assuming this isn't the "intended" solution for this problem but I'm interested nonetheless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a classical approach without much computation.

For any prime $p$, we may estimate its exponent in $\binom{2n}{n}$ as follows
$$\nu_p\biggl(\binom{2n}{n}\biggr)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_p2n\rfloor}\biggl(\Bigl\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^k}\Bigr\rfloor-2\Bigl\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\Bigr\rfloor\biggr)\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_p2n\rfloor}1\leqslant\log_p2n.$$
So we have
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\prod_{\text{prime}~p\\p<2n}p^{\nu_p\bigl(\binom{2n}{n}\bigr)}\leqslant\prod_{\text{prime}~p\\p<2n}p^{\log_p2n}=\prod_{\text{prime}~p\\p<2n}2n=(2n)^{\pi(2n)}.$$
For $n>1$, we also have
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{n+k}{k}>\prod_{k=1}^n2=2^n.$$
This proved the second inequality.

For the first one, just note that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is divisible by any prime $p$ in the region $(n,2n)$, therefore
$$\binom{2n}{n}\geqslant\prod_{\text{prime}~p\\n<p<2n}p\geqslant\prod_{\text{prime}~p\\n<p<2n}n=n^{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)}.$$
Then $\binom{2n}{n}<\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=2^{2n}$ gives the disired result.

Comment: That's an elegant one, +1

Comment: Thank you, indeed very elegant :)

Comment: @AdarHefer We all should thank Erdős, who brought [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) from _the book_ to us.

Comment: That's Tchebychef's original method I think

Answer (score 1):

Using [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) (and some discussions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n/206822#206822))

$$\frac{x}{\ln{x}}<\pi(x)< 1.25506\frac{x}{\ln{x}} \text{, for } x \geq 17 \tag{1}$$

---

**The second one** $2^n \leq (2n)^{\pi(2n)}$ is a direct result of $\pi(x)>\frac{x}{\ln{x}}$
or
$$\pi(2n)>\frac{2n}{\ln{(2n)}}>\frac{n\ln{2}}{\ln{(2n)}} \Rightarrow \pi(2n) \cdot \ln{(2n)} > n \cdot \ln{2} \Rightarrow \\
\ln{(2n)^{\pi(2n)}}>\ln{2^n} \Rightarrow (2n)^{\pi(2n)} > 2^n$$

---

**The first one**
$$n^{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)}< 2^{2n} \Leftrightarrow \left(\pi(2n)-\pi(n) \right) \ln{n} < 2n \ln{2} \tag{2}$$
but
$$1.25506 < 2\ln{2}$$
and it is enough to prove
$$\color{red}{\pi(2n)-\pi(n) < \pi(n)} < 1.25506\frac{n}{\ln{n}} < 2 \ln{2}\frac{n}{\ln{n}}$$

which is covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738347/proving-that-pi2x-2-pix).