# Tchebychef's theorem that the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ has order of magnitude $x/\log(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Where can I find a modern (preferably elementary) proof of Tchebychef's 1852 theorem that the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ has order of magnitude $x/\log(x)$. Perferrably with the original bounds as outlined in the first two pages of [this survey article of prof. D. Goldfeld](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf). I will also count as modern Tchebychef's original approach coated in modern notation and terminology. Basically I only require this so that I am most likely to understand it as well as possible, not because of a particular dislike for Tchebychef's method itself, which I think is very cool from the outlines provided in the mentioned paper. I speak nor read French very well.

Comment: P.L. Tchebychef,
M ́
emoire sur les nombres premiers,
J. de Math. Pures Appl. (1)
17
(1852), 366–390; reprinted in Oeuvres
1
(1899), 49–70.

Comment: And adapt this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408311/276986)